# How is this quad exercise called?

Tags: exercise

Does anybody know how the two exercises on [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ja0AAXg3Rnk&feature=plcp) are called?

In fact it seems to be one exercise and a variation of it, but perhaps the variation has a custom name.

I want to search more information about this exercise and workouts, which include it, but to to so I should know how it is called.

If it has different names in different contexts, please let me know.

Comment: Looks like this is a variation on pelvic tilts is all.

Comment: Could you describe what is going on in the video instead of just linking to it? If the video disappears, then the questions loses its value.

Comment: Yes, I will include it in the next few days. If you want, feel free to edit my question and add the description.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen anyone do it, but I think the full version of the exercise, where you stand all the way up, is called the "Sissy Squat" (sorry for the title):
[Sissy Squat](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Quadriceps/BWSissySquat.html)
[Weighted Sissy Squat](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Quadriceps/WTSissySquat.html)

Comment: FWIW, I'd think that regular bodyweight squats would be more healthy for your knees.

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: Because a bodyweight squat can be self limiting for range of motion, and the location of your center of gravity in relation to your knees/legs is different. In a squat, your body weight remains pretty much centered over your legs, in this kind of an exercise (sissy squat), your body weight is way behind your knees, which places a much different stress on them. And, if you lose your grip, then all your weight is going backwards.

Comment: I found this one where it is also called "modifiex sissy squat": http://www.fitnessmagazine.com/workout/thighs/exercises/lower-body-workout/?page=2

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a [Pure Barre](http://purebarre.com/p-story.html) exercise.  Pure Barre is a newer version of [Callanetics](http://callanetics.com/).  The techniques use high rep, short range isometrics in specific positions to target deep postural muscles.  They both have a basis in ballet and have Pilates type moves.  They can be very effective in targeting deep postural muscle.